# Python, Protoc, Mac OS, Missing input file

Tags: python, macos

Файлы .proto хранятся в: `/Users/alarih/Documents/objectdetection/object_detection/protos`

Терминал:

```
protoc -I=/Users/alarih/Documents/objectdetection/object_detection/protos --python_out=/Users/alarih/Documents/objectdetection/object_detection/protos/*.proto
Missing input file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `protoc -I <path>` или `protoc --proto_path=<path>`:

```
protoc -I /Users/alarih/Documents/objectdetection/object_detection/protos --python_out=/Users/alarih/Documents/objectdetection/object_detection/protos/*.proto

protoc --proto_path=/Users/alarih/Documents/objectdetection/object_detection/protos --python_out=/Users/alarih/Documents/objectdetection/object_detection/protos/*.proto
```